# why do some applications exit on their own without giving notification, error, or whatsoever?

Tags: 11.10

I have ubuntu 11.10. I installed pcsx yesterday and that application exits on its own for a random time interval. Its not giving me any error or notification. So what may be the cause of it exiting on its own?

Answer (score 2):

Probably a crash. If it's always the same application, you should run it from the terminal and see if error messages are printed during the crash.

Open a terminal by pressing `ctrl`+`alt`+`t` or typing `terminal` in the dash.

Comment: how do I run an application through terminal?